# Segmentation Fault 11 linking os x 32-bit assembler

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, 32-bit, libc

UPDATE: Sure enough, it was a bug in the latest version of nasm. I "downgraded" and after fixing my code as shown in the answer I accepted, everything is working properly.  Thanks, everyone!

I'm having problems with what should be a very simple program in 32-bit assembler on OS X.

First, the code:

```
section .data
hello   db  "Hello, world", 0x0a, 0x00

section .text
default rel

global _main
extern _printf, _exit

_main:
    sub esp, 12     ; 16-byte align stack
    push hello
    call _printf

    push 0
    call _exit
```

It assembles and links, but when I run the executable it crashes with a segmentation fault: 11.

The command lines to assemble and link are:

```
nasm -f macho32 hello32x.asm -o hello32x.o
```

I know the -o there is not 100 percent necessary

Linking:

```
ld -lc -arch i386 hello32x.o -o hello32x
```

When I run it into lldb to debug it, everything is fine until it enters into the call to _printf, where it crashes as shown below:

```
  (lldb) s
  Process 1029 stopped
  * thread #1: tid = 0x97a4, 0x00001fac hello32x`main + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = instruction step into
      frame #0: 0x00001fac hello32x`main + 8
  hello32x`main:
  ->  0x1fac <+8>:  calll  0xffffffff991e381e
      0x1fb1 <+13>: pushl  $0x0
      0x1fb3 <+15>: calll  0xffffffff991fec84
      0x1fb8:       addl   %eax, (%eax)
  (lldb) s
  Process 1029 stopped
  * thread #1: tid = 0x97a4, 0x991e381e libsystem_c.dylib`vfprintf + 49, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = instruction step into
      frame #0: 0x991e381e libsystem_c.dylib`vfprintf + 49
  libsystem_c.dylib`vfprintf:
  ->  0x991e381e <+49>: xchgb  %ah, -0x76f58008
      0x991e3824 <+55>: popl   %esp
      0x991e3825 <+56>: andb   $0x14, %al
      0x991e3827 <+58>: movl   0xc(%ebp), %ecx
  (lldb) s
  Process 1029 stopped
  * thread #1: tid = 0x97a4, 0x991e381e libsystem_c.dylib`vfprintf + 49, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x890a7ff8)
      frame #0: 0x991e381e libsystem_c.dylib`vfprintf + 49
  libsystem_c.dylib`vfprintf:
  ->  0x991e381e <+49>: xchgb  %ah, -0x76f58008
      0x991e3824 <+55>: popl   %esp
      0x991e3825 <+56>: andb   $0x14, %al
      0x991e3827 <+58>: movl   0xc(%ebp), %ecx
```

As you can see toward the bottom, it stops due to a bad access error.

Comment: I am pretty sure you also get at least a warning during linking. Anyway, this looks like the usual case of not letting the C library initialize. Use `gcc` to link.

Comment: Hi @Jester. Yes, I get an error:

ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from hello32x.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie

but I get the same error if I use gcc to link.

Comment: I reasoned out a bug in my code - I should have only done sub esp, 8, because pushing the string's address to the stack would bring it to 12, and then the push of the return address by the call brings it to 16, making the 16-byte stack alignment needed by OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 16-byte Stack Alignment

One serious issue with your code is stack alignment. 32-bit OS/X code requires 16-byte stack alignment at the point you make a *CALL*. The [Apple IA-32 Calling Convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002492-SW4) says this:

> The function calling conventions used in the IA-32 environment are the same as those used in the [System V IA-32 ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), with the following exceptions:
>
> - Different rules for returning structures
> - The **stack is 16-byte aligned** at the point of function calls
> - Large data types (larger than 4 bytes) are kept at their natural alignment
> - Most floating-point operations are carried out using the SSE unit instead of the x87 FPU, except when operating on long double values. (The IA-32 environment defaults to 64-bit internal precision for the x87 FPU.)

You subtract 12 from *ESP*  to align the stack to a 16 byte boundary (4 bytes for return address + 12 = 16). The problem is that when you make a *CALL* to a function the stack MUST be 16 bytes aligned just prior to the *CALL* itself. Unfortunately you push 4 bytes before the call to `printf` and `exit`. This misaligns the stack by 4, when it should be aligned to 16 bytes. You'll have to rework the code with proper alignment. As well you must clean up the stack after you make a call. If you use *PUSH* to put parameters on the stack you need to adjust *ESP* after your *CALL* to restore the stack to its previous state.

One naive way (not my recommendation) to fix the code would be to do this:

```
section .data
hello   db  "Hello, world", 0x0a, 0x00

section .text
default rel

global _main
extern _printf, _exit

_main:
    sub esp, 8     
    push hello     ; 4(return address)+ 8 + 4 = 16 bytes stack aligned
    call _printf
    add esp, 4     ; Remove arguments

    push 0         ; 4 + 8 + 4 = 16 byte alignment again
    call _exit     ; This will not return so no need to remove parameters after
```

The code above works because we can take advantage of the fact that both functions (`exit` and `printf`) require exactly one *DWORD* being placed on the stack for parameters. 4 bytes for `main`'s return address, 8 for the stack adjustment we made, 4 for the *DWORD* parameter = 16 byte alignment.

---

A better way to do this is to compute the amount of stack space you will need for all your stack based local variables (in this case 0) in your `main` function, plus the maximum number of bytes you will need for any parameters to function calls made by `main` and then make sure you pad enough bytes to make the value evenly divisible by 12. In our case the maximum number of bytes needed to be pushed for any one given function call is 4 bytes. We then add 8 to 4 (8+4=12) to become evenly divisible by 12. We then subtract 12 from *ESP* at the start of our function.

Instead of using *PUSH* to put parameters on the stack you can now move the parameters directly onto the stack into the space we have reserved. Because we don't *PUSH* the stack doesn't get misaligned. Since we didn't use *PUSH* we don't need to fix *ESP* after our function calls. The code could then look something like:

```
section .data
hello   db  "Hello, world", 0x0a, 0x00

section .text
default rel

global _main
extern _printf, _exit

_main:
    sub esp, 12           ; 16-byte align stack + room for parameters passed
                          ; to functions we call
    mov [esp],dword hello ; First parameter at esp+0
    call _printf

    mov [esp], dword 0    ; First parameter at esp+0
    call _exit
```

If you wanted to pass multiple parameters you place them manually on the stack as we did with a single parameter. If we wanted to print an integer 42 as part of our call to `printf` we could do it this way:

```
section .data
hello   db  "Hello, world %d", 0x0a, 0x00

section .text
default rel

global _main
extern _printf, _exit

_main:
    sub esp, 12           ; 16-byte align stack + room for parameters passed
                          ; to functions we call

    mov [esp+4], dword 42 ; Second parameter at esp+4
    mov [esp],dword hello ; First parameter at esp+0
    call _printf

    mov [esp], dword 0    ; First parameter at esp+0
    call _exit
```

When run we should get:

> Hello, world 42

---

### 16-byte Stack Alignment and a Stack Frame

If you are looking to create a function with a typical stack frame then the code in the previous section has to be adjusted. Upon entry to a function in a 32-bit application the stack is misaligned by 4 bytes because the return address was placed on the stack. A typical stack frame prologue looks like:

```
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
```

Pushing *EBP* into the stack after entry to your function still results in a misaligned stack, but it is misaligned now by 8 bytes (4 + 4).

Because of that the code must subtract 8 from *ESP* rather than 12. As well when determining the space needed to hold parameters, local stack variables, and pad bytes for alignment the stack allocation size will have to be evenly divisible by 8, not by 12. Code with a stack frame could look like:

```
section .data
hello   db  "Hello, world %d", 0x0a, 0x00

section .text
default rel

global _main
extern _printf, _exit

_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp          ; Set up stack frame
    sub esp, 8            ; 16-byte align stack + room for parameters passed
                          ; to functions we call

    mov [esp+4], dword 42 ; Second parameter at esp+4
    mov [esp],dword hello ; First parameter at esp+0
    call _printf

    xor eax, eax          ; Return value = 0
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp               ; Remove stack frame
    ret                   ; We linked with C library that calls _main
                          ; after initialization. We can do a RET to
                          ; return back to the C runtime code that will
                          ; exit the program and return the value in EAX
                          ; We can do this instead of calling _exit
```

Because you link with the *C* library on OS/X it will provide an entry point and do initialization before calling `_main`. You can call `_exit` but you can also do a *RET* instruction with the program's return value in *EAX*.

---

### Yet Another Potential NASM Bug?

I discovered that *NASM* v2.12 installed via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=nasm) on *El Capitan* seems to generate incorrect relocation entries for `_printf` and `_exit`, and when linked to a final executable the code doesn't work as expected. I observed almost the identical errors you did with your original code.

The first part of my answer still applies about stack alignment, however it appears you will need to work around the *NASM* issue as well. One way to do this install the *NASM* that comes with the latest XCode command line tools. This version is much older and only supports Macho-32, and doesn't support the `default` directive. Using my previous stack aligned code this should work:

```
section .data
hello   db  "Hello, world %d", 0x0a, 0x00

section .text
;default rel              ; This directive isn't supported in older versions of NASM

global _main
extern _printf, _exit

_main:
    sub esp, 12           ; 16-byte align stack
    mov [esp+4], dword 42 ; Second parameter at esp+4
    mov [esp],dword hello ; First parameter at esp+0
    call _printf

    mov [esp], dword 0    ; First parameter at esp+0
    call _exit
```

To assemble with *NASM* and link with *LD* you could use:

```
/usr/bin/nasm -f macho hello32x.asm -o hello32x.o
ld -macosx_version_min 10.8 -no_pie -arch i386 -o hello32x hello32x.o -lc
```

Alternatively you could link with *GCC*:

```
/usr/bin/nasm -f macho hello32x.asm -o hello32x.o
gcc -m32 -Wl,-no_pie -o hello32x hello32x.o
```

`/usr/bin/nasm` is the location of the XCode command line tools version of *NASM* that Apple distributes. The version I have on *El Capitan* with latest XCode command line tools is:

> NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on Jan 14 2016

I don't recommend *NASM* version 2.11.08 because it has a [serious bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132147/3857942) related to macho64 format. I recommend [2.11.09rc2](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.09rc2/macosx/). I have tested that version here and it does seem to work properly with the code above.

Comment: Yes, this is probably also an issue, but from the gdb log it doesn't seem to be an alignment problem. Normally this only bites people if they use floating point since then `printf` may use aligned SSE instructions.

Comment: @jester OS/X functions (especially in _LIBC_) are pretty finicky about the stack alignment, and you'll get problems even when not using SSE at all.

Comment: Surely not problems where execution goes into strange places? Anyway, I'll take your word for it if you swear you checked this with `ld -lc` as OP did and it worked.

Comment: @Jester : I've seen stranger! I actually have seen this myself many times. When I answered this question I was able to reproduce the OPs problem as described, and when the stack was properly aligned things worked as expected. I saw your comment about the _LIBC_ initialization. The way OP did things he is actually linking with _LIBC_ properly, and the _C_ runtime will do its initialization and then call `_main` . He could have simplified linkage by using _GCC_ as you pointed out.

Comment: Okay. On linux, the process entry point will be set to `_main` so it won't be called through the C library. `ld` even prints a warning `cannot find entry symbol _start`. Among other things this means you can't just `ret` from it and it doesn't get the arguments normally. I believe you that it's different on OSX but it sounds strange. Can you check in gdb just to be sure?

Comment: @Jester On Linux the entry point by default is `_start` and GLIBC provides it. It then makes a call to `main`. OS/X is similar in that regard. `ret` would have worked instead of a call to `exit` (I considered suggesting that change in his code, but decided to keep his code as is), but as an experiment I removed the call to `exit` I added 12 to _ESP_ at the bottom set EAX with a value (99), and did a `ret`. The program returned to the shell as expected with the return value 99. Stepping through the debugger you can see it returning back through the _C_ library code that originally called _main

Comment: No, `_start` is **not** in `-lc` on linux, it's in an object file you need to link separately. Looks like OSX differs in this regard, thanks for checking :)

Comment: @Jester Oops sorry I mispoke, I typed it quickly. on linux you need to provide `_start` through the `crt` files, or link them in automatically with _GCC_ . OS/X differs in that you can link directly with _LD_ using the LIBC for the target OS/X platform which fulfills the entry point for the OS/X version you build for. You can circumvent this behavior when linking with _LD_ on OSX by providing your own entry point but then you won't have the _C_ runtime executed automatically and then you'll run into potential issues just like Linux.

Comment: OK @MichaelPetch I just copied Michael's code _verbatim_ into a new file, assembled it and linked it. I still have a seg fault. I am beginning to think something is off with my development software, because I can't see any reason why the code won't work. I've tried linking with gcc instead of using ld and have the same error.

I'm going on a business trip and i won't be able to work on this for a week. I will be back, though, and I will do what I can to find a solution.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @querist :what version of OSX are you using?

Comment: @querist : And I also hope you recompiled the file with NASM and did the linking. I just tried my code with `gcc -m32  hello32x.o -o hello32x -Wl,-no_pie` and it worked as expected as well. So using both _LD_ and _GCC_ did work here. If I take your original code, it definitely has issues calling printf just as you found

Comment: I was wrong about the actual error in lldb being the same. When I run your code it actually dies in printf but with `* thread #1: tid = 0x4452c3, 0x9bbe9440 libdyld.dylib misaligned_stack_error_, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` . The only thing is I still use OS/X Yosemite 10.10.x. Sp there does seem to be some difference with your environment

Comment: Hi @MichaelPetch, I'm running El Capitan. I tried the code into a new file, compiled and linked as described above. I also tried it on my son's machine running Mountain Lion with a much older version of nasm and it worked. Unfortunately, I'm in the airport on my way for a business trip that will take a week and I have a company computer with me, not my mac. I am checking for updates for XCode and related tools. I'm also going to check the latest version of nasm on my son's computer when I go back.
 You guys are great. Thanks again to you, Jester, and Peter Cordes.

Comment: @querist I guess it is possible something changed with El Capitan in this regard, but I must admit could be unaware of it. If I get a chance to install it today, I'll try it out. Have a good trip.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelPetch ! I'm safely in my hotel now, but a thousand miles away from my Macbook Pro so I can't do much more on this one until I get back.

Comment: @querist :  Seems that there is a bug in the NASM you are probably using. I was able to reproduce the problem with Macports version of NASM (2.12) on El Capitan. Seems that 2.12 generates wrong relocation entries for `_printf_` and `_exit`. I was able to use the antiquated version of NASM in /usr/bin/nasm (NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11)) that comes with the latest XCode and it works fine. The old version doesn't support 64-bit macho, but it does support 32-bit. Have to make a couple mods to code. Add the `bits 32` to the top of file and remove `default rel` directive

Comment: Hi @MichaelPetch, I will re-install 2.11 when I get back to my house. I still have the installer somewhere.

Comment: @querist, when you do get back home, I recommend 2.11.09rc2 (I've updated my answer at the bottom with some additional info)

Comment: I've "downgraded", tested, and it works perfectly. Thanks, @MichaelPetch!