# Segmentation Fault: 11 in NASM assembled OS/X code that works on Win32

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, libc

I have this code which compiled perfectly fine (compiled and working) on a windows laptop but when I try it on a Mac, I get a `segmentation fault: 11`.

This is how I compiled it on a windows:

```
nasm –f win32 bub.asm
gcc bub.obj –o bub.exe
```

Compiled at terminal with:

```
nasm -f macho bub.asm
ld -o bub bub.o -arch i386 -lc -no_pie -macosx_version_min 10.10
./bub
```

My code:

```
global _main
extern _printf, _scanf, _system, _getchar

section .text

_main:
    pushad                      

    call _clearScreen           
    call _inputSize             

    mov ECX, [num_elements]     

    call _inputNumbers          
    call _printArray            
    call _sort      

    push message
    call _printf
    add ESP, 4

    call _printArray        

    popad                       

    ret

_sort:
    mov EDI, [num_elements]         
        DEC EDI                     


    do:
        mov ESI, 0                  
        mov ECX, EDI                

        lea EAX, [elements]         
        lea EBX, [elements + 4]     

        for:
            mov EDX, [EAX]          
            cmp EDX, [EBX]      

            JLE endif                   

            xchg edx, [ebx]         
            mov dword[eax], edx         

            mov ESI, 1  

            endif:
                add eax, 4      
                add ebx, 4      

            LOOP for                        

        cmp ESI, 0                  
        JNE do          

    ret

_inputSize:
    push prompt1    
    call _printf                
    add ESP, 4              

    push num_elements       
    push scanformat         
    call _scanf
    add ESP, 8              
    call _getchar               

    ret

_inputNumbers:
    mov EBX, elements       
    mov EDX, 0              

    enterNumber:
        push EBX            
        push EDX            
        push ECX            

        push prompt2            
        call _printf            
        add ESP, 4              

        push element            
        push scanformat     
        call _scanf         
        add ESP, 8              
        call _getchar       

        pop ECX                 
        pop EDX             
        pop EBX             

        mov EAX, dword [element]    
        mov [EBX + EDX], EAX        
        add EDX, 4              

        loop enterNumber
    ret

_printArray:
    push output1                
    call _printf            
    add ESP, 4              

    mov ECX, [num_elements]     
    mov ESI, 0              

    printArray:
        push ECX            

        push dword [elements + ESI] 
        push dword output2      
        call _printf                
        add ESP, 8              

        pop ECX             

        add ESI, 4              
        loop printArray     

    ret


_clearScreen:
    push clr
    call _system
    add ESP, 4
    ret

section .data
    clr                 db "cls", 0
    scanformat          db "%d", 0

    prompt1             db "Enter number of elements: ", 0
    prompt2             db "Enter number: ", 0

    output1             db "Array Contents: ", 0
    output2             db "%d ", 0

    message             db "Array sorted!", 13, 10, 0
    bye                 db "goodbye", 13, 10, 0

    num_elements        dd 0
    elements times 100  dd 0
    element             dd 0
```

Comment: Debugger would be helpful to check where it happens. It might be because of differences in calling conventions. At least on OS X you need to set EAX to zero before calling printf since it may have a variable number of arguments.

Comment: What version of _NASM_ are you using? (`nasm -v` should tell you)

Comment: Part of the 32-bit OS/X ABI is that all function calls are to be 16-byte (yes byte) aligned just prior to a function call. Failure to do this generally causes a segfault of type "Misaligned Stack" if you were to use a debugger (like _LLDB_) to debug it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen : Zeroing _EAX_ only applies to the 64-bit OS/X calling convention. It doesn't apply to 32-bit code OS/X code.

Comment: I recently wrote this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35964976/3857942) about OS/X 32-bit code and especially the alignment issue. If your version of _NASM_ is 2.12 you may also want to heed the advice in the lower part of my answer as well.

Comment: I'd recommend running this command (you'll likely only need to do it once for LLDB debugger to have proper permissions): `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable` . Now you should be able to run `lldb` to debug. Do `lldb ./bub` . Now type `run` at the LLDB prompt. If you see something like `libdyld.dylib'misaligned_stack_error_, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS` then your problem is almost guaranteed to be the 16-byte alignment issue.

Comment: NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on Nov 11 2015. Yup, it's the 16-byte alignment issue, thanks for this :D