# How to link a NASM code and GCC in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm unable to link my code with gcc, check this code:

```
extern printf
global main
section .data
  mensaje: db "Hola mundo!", 10,0
section .text
main:
  push mensaje
  call printf
  add esp, 4
ret
```

The output I get is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable
>     "printf", referenced from:
>         main in holamundo.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using this command:

> **nasm -f macho32 holamundo.asm**

and gcc command(I get the error, here):

> **gcc -m32 holamundo.o -o holamundo**

Thanks in advance, my english is ever bad.

Comment: Try to rename your `main` into `_main`.

Comment: I renamed `printf` and `main` to `_printf` and `_main`, but I get this `ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from holamundo.o. To fix this warning,
 don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie` and when I run the executable I get this `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: Have you tried to follow the advice in that warning?

Comment: @fuz I am not compiling with using `-mdynamic-no-pic`, `-Wl` or `-no_pie` how Do you think I should compile?

Comment: I'm not sure this will help but at the bottom of an answer I gave on SO previously I had given a way to use _LD_ and _GCC_ to link to an executable on OS/X: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35964976/3857942  . The very last section of that answer may help.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Your answers ever are so useful, I'm using: `nasm -f macho holamundo.asm -o holamundo.o` and `gcc -m32 -Wl,-no_pie -o holamundo holamundo.o` but I get this: `Segmentation fault: 11` :(

Comment: If those lines compile then I must assume you are using Apple's version of _NASM_ (which is good). I suspect that the reason for your failure is that you haven't properly aligned the stack to a 16-byte boundary before calling `printf` . That same answer I linked to sort of discusses that in the section _16-byte Stack Alignment and a Stack Frame_

Comment: In your case here you don't use a stack frame. The stack is misaligned by 4 bytes after control is transferred to your function `main` (since the return address was put on the stack). Pushing your message parameter with `push mensaje` means the stack is now misaligned by 8. To get that to work you need to add an additional 8 bytes to _ESP_ to make sure the stack is back on a 16-byte boundary before the call to `printf` So code like this probably would work `sub esp, 8`
  `push mensaje`
  `call _printf`
  `add esp, 12` `ret`

Comment: This is discussed in Apple's IA-32 Calling convention here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html . It says _The stack is 16-byte aligned at the point of function calls_ . The reason for this is that OS/X calls will use certain instructions that require alignment (aligned instructions perform better than unaligned) like certain _SIMD_ vector instructions (ie: [movdqa](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQA.html))

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wow! Thank you so much. ^^ your code works!!! I'm reading whole your answer. It's so exciting. Michael, you are my hero. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135643/discussion-between-omar-murcia-and-michael-petch).